# Are these Apple software bugs resolved?

Tags: ios, bug

I came across this article: http://www.cestarcollege.com/blog/software-development/the-3-most-devastating-bugs-found-in-recent-software/ which is talking about 3 bugs found in Apple software. Are these resolved now?  Does anyone have any idea about these bugs?

Answer (score 2):

The three problems mentioned in the article have all been addressed by Apple.

### Apple Maps Misdirection – 2012

Apple Maps are constantly being updated.

### Gotofail – 2014

[Fixed four days later](http://macdailynews.com/2014/02/25/apple-fixes-os-x-gotofail-security-flaw-after-four-days-of-snowballing-criticism/) on Tuesday, February 25, 2014. The article linked in the question was published on 30 October 2017.

### Heartbleed – 2014

[Heartbleed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heartbleed) was not an Apple specific bug. It was a bug in the open source OpenSSL project, which was rapidly fixed.